# How to manually set exit code of a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

As the title, can I somehow set the exit code for a docker container? 
My makefile for now looks like this:

```
docker ps -qa | xargs docker rm -f
docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose ps -q | xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .State.ExitCode }}' | while [ $$(docker-compose ps -q | xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }}  {{ .State }}' | grep running | grep -vc grep) -gt 1 ];\
            do if (grep -v 0) ; then echo exit -1; fi;\
            done
```

This is the docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  dev-server:
    build: .
    hostname: dev_server
    container_name: dev_server
    ports: 
      - 127.0.0.01:8080:8080
      - 35729:35729
    command: npm run dev-server 

  headless-chrome:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-headless-chrome
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    network_mode: "host"

  unit-test:
    build: .
    entrypoint: npm
    command: test
```

Im running three containers whereas two run tests and exit either 1 or 0. If any of them exit 1 I would like to "force my container to exit with code 1" too, is this possible?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you run the container. `docker run`? a compose setup? other?

Comment: See the above changes :) @Grimmy

Comment: So you have 3 containers. They get built and spin up altogether, 2 of those runs tests and if any one of them exits with `1` then you would like the remaining running containers to be forcefully terminated ? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes "@SamuelToh